# PHP strict code validation

Tags: php, phpeclipse

I use PHPClipse for my PHP development.  It has some code highlighting and some other validation such as forgetting to put a ';' at the end of a statement or forgetting '}' etc.  I find it is easy to make a mistakes, for example

```
class foo {
    private $test;

    function __construct() {
        $test = new stdClass;
        $test->myVar = "hello";
    }

    function getTest() {
        echo $this->test->myVar;
    }
}
```

This should have been `$this->test = 6;`

In code when things like this happen in conditionals such as `if else` the only time you realise is when the `else` statement executes which might be after the software was delivered to clients.

Other examples may be displaying a warning when a function from an abstract class is not implemented.

Is there a way, particularly in Eclipse, that you can turn on some sort of STRICT validate which highlights anything that might be a little dubious?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is there an error in the above code?

Comment: There is no error, the problem is that the $test variable is local to the function where the intention was to use the class variable.  It is easy to make these sorts of mistakes in PHP.  I updated the question to use an object to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the PHPEclipse version from http://www.phpeclipse.com/ there should be some code analysis options under "Preferences / PHPeclipse / PHP / PHP Parser -> Style"

You can select warnings for uninitialized variables and unreachable code.

I'm not sure if there are anything similar available for the PHP Development Tools Project http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

No checkbox for dubious code, though...

Comment: I am using PHPEclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/.  I can't find this menu you are talking about.  I have Window->Preferences->PHP->editor->code Assist.  But that is all and they don't have the warnings you mentioned.  Are these versions different?

Comment: I am installing this now. What is the difference between this and the PHP PDT?

Comment: Late warning, but I don't think they work well together, so you might want to install it to a fresh eclipse install...

Answer (score 0):

Warnings when using a local var instead of object var is not something you should expect from your editor, that's just bad programming.

I know for a fact that [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/) does a pretty thorough analysis on your code, for example warning you when you forget to implement a certain method.

Comment: Bad programming is writing large functions, slow algorithms or writing difficult to understand code.  The quirky workings of a particular programming language are the fault of the designers not the users.  Arguably it is PHP that is 'bad' as the syntax distinction between local, global and class members is a little blurry.

Comment: The wordings 'bad programming' are probably not the best. What I meant to say was that it's just a programmer's mistake, and it can't be detected by a parser. Weird thing to say that PHP is bad because it distinguishes between local and object scope.